# php line change including space for string

Tags: php

I need to put hyperlinks for the strings, but the line break is wrong. I need to change line per string, so underlined links don't mix up each other.

```
$aaa = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 
$aaa = 'bbbbbbb'; 
$aaa = 'ccccccc cccccc'; 


for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
{ 
   echo $aaa; 
   echo ' '; ----->space between string
}
```

Currently, I'm getting wrong outputs below:

```
wrong output1:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb
bbbb

wrong output2:
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc 
cccccc
```

I need to print out like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb 
ccccccc cccccc
```

I tried  and  , but it still change line per at space.

===========================================
Updated question:
Ok, i think my explanation was so bad:

Think about you print out this values from database using FOR loop:

```
google images
google email
google mail
google books
google earth
google voice
google scholar
google finance
```

I'm printing out them in line like below. 

google images
google email
google mail
google books
google earth
google voice

My concern was sometimes it prints out below:
google images
google email
google mail
google books
google earth
google
 voice

Comment: use &nbsp; instead of space

Comment: `$aaa` has value `ccccccc cccccc` when enters in loop. No way to get those outputs.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do here. It'd help if you include an actual example. This code, you're currently using doesn't make any sense, and it'll just print `ccccccc cccccc` 3 times.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your problem as its not clear what your problem is and what do you want.

Answer (score 1):

You rewrite your variable values here.

```
$aaa = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 
$aaa = 'bbbbbbb'; 
$aaa = 'ccccccc cccccc';
```

You should need to look like this

```
$aaa = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' 
$aaa .= 'bbbbbbb'; 
$aaa .= 'ccccccc cccccc';
```

But if you want your result, here is little example

```
$array_str = array('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbb', 'ccccccc cccccc');
foreach($array_str as $value) {
    echo $value.'   ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that If string has space, put the new break line, use following codes

```
<?php

$a[1] = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa';
$a[2] = 'bbbbbbb'; 
$a[3] = 'ccccccc cccccc'; 


for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
{ 
    if(preg_match('/\s/', $a[$i]))
        echo "<br />";
    echo $a[$i]; 
    echo ' ';
} 

?>
```

`if(preg_match('/\s/', $a[$i]))` this match with space

#### Output

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbb 
ccccccc cccccc
```